# ttyACM or ttyUSB device detection

Tags: udev, ttyusb

I develop a linux application, which works with `ttyUSB*`/`ttyACM*` devices. Now I have a task:
I have to find a way, how to restore communication with device, when connection is temporary lost. Now I see such a behaviour: if port is opened in the app, and device is re-pluged at this moment, the device's name changes, and app can not complete current operation. So, I wrote `udev` rule to add symlink to device, and the rule works. But app crashes all the same. The reason is that device changes it's `tty` (`ttyACM0->tyyACM1`) after re-plugging, and symlink does not help, because file descriptor becames wrong.

Does anybody know a way, how can I replug device without need to restart my app? Are there any settings in Linux to allow device to re-plug to the same `tty` even if it was opened in the application in the moment of disconnection?

Comment: If you have an open file descriptor associated with the device, and you unplug/replug it, you'd have to re-open the device.  That doesn't mean you have to restart the program, per se, the program itself could handle that case.

Comment: Sad, but true. I'm afraid, you are right =) But, is there at least a way to re-plug  device to the same ttyUSB* (not to the same alias)?

Comment: Can your udev rule uniquely identify the device?  Will there ever be only one such device connected at a time?  If so, I think you could make your udev rule always update the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came to a conclusion, that a manual management of open/close port descriptor is the only solution to the problem.
Also, some moments may affect to the device's behaviour:

- USB timeout settings
- modemmanager presence
- interval between plug and unplug the device